# Priority of SIGSEG and Floating Point protection

Tags: c++, memory, floating-point, operating-system

I have written a routine that is designed to allow a client to load and use their own dll within my code.  Because I have no control over the quality of the client's dll, I am trying to report every error I can think of clearly and concisely - otherwise they will assume the problem is in my code.

I have got several layers of protection, but it seems now as though two of those levels are conflicting with each other.

The segmentation fault protection is:

```
void (*previous_sigsegv_function)(int);                    // This caches the function that is currently encountered when a segmentation fault is encountered.
previous_sigsegv_function = signal(SIGSEGV, terminate_immediately);    // This registers with the OS the function to execute is a segmentation fault is encountered.

// Run client dll

signal(SIGSEGV, previous_sigsegv_function);    // This resets the sigseg function to the original.
```

This has worked quite well in the past (and I don't believe it is controversial).

The floating point protection was a bit more difficult (and lead to a few questions being asked here), but I ended up encoding it as a macro:

```
    #define CATCH_FLOATING_POINT_EXCEPTION(EXPR, CONTROL, ERROR_FOUND) \
    unsigned int __previous_control;  \
    _controlfp_s(&__previous_control, CONTROL, _MCW_EM);   \
    __try {  \
        EXPR;  \
        _controlfp_s(NULL, __previous_control, _MCW_EM);  \
    }  \
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)  \
    {  \
        strncpy_s(ERROR_FOUND, MAX_FP_ERROR_LENGTH, __describe_floating_point_error(GetExceptionCode()), MAX_FP_ERROR_LENGTH);  \
        _controlfp_s(NULL, __previous_control, _MCW_EM);  \
    }
```

And then used thus:

```
        CATCH_FLOATING_POINT_EXCEPTION(result = function(this->turbine_id),                 // DISCON_TYPEDEF returns an int.
                                       SERIOUS_FP_EXCEPTIONS,
                                       floating_point_error);    // This is a char* to return the error (if there is one).
```

This also works.

Where it all comes unstuck is that I've recently created an integration test and it seems as though the segmentation fault (created by deliberately using a corrupted pointer) is being incorrectly reported as a divide-by-zero error.

Is this a fault in my test (such as really bad luck in managing to generate a divide by zero from dodgy memory), or is there some interaction between the two error-trapping mechanisms?

**EDIT:**

I believe this is partially down to how I was generating the segmentation fault.  I have redone it such that it definitely obliterates vital memory, and this correctly triggers the segmentation fault protection.

HOWEVER, in Debug mode it behaves exactly as expected (going straight into the terminate function).  In Release mode, however, it registers both a divide-by-zero and then a segmentation fault.  This is acceptable behaviour, but a bit odd.

My question thus becomes: why does the floating point machine get confused by the segmentation fault?  And possibly more pertinently: why is the SIGSEGV event delayed in Release mode, allowing the code to report the floating point error before terminating?

Comment: I wish the person who had down-voted this question could have posted something constructive first - it's obviously so obvious to them that the question doesn't have merit, but it's a difficult issue that I've been unable to get a real answer to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've returned to this issue while trying to sort out another problem, and I now understand why the two mechanisms are interacting.

The SIGSEV protection is on the outside, and inside that is the floating point trap:

```
unsigned int _previous_floating_point_control;  \


_controlfp_s(&_previous_floating_point_control, 0, 0);   \
    _controlfp_s(nullptr, CONTROL, _MCW_EM);   \
    __try {  \
        EXPR;  \
        _controlfp_s(nullptr, _previous_floating_point_control, _MCW_EM);  \
    }  \
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)  \
    {  \
        strncpy_s(ERROR_FOUND, MAX_FP_ERROR_LENGTH, _describe_floating_point_error(GetExceptionCode()), MAX_FP_ERROR_LENGTH);  \
        _controlfp_s(nullptr, _previous_floating_point_control, _MCW_EM);  \
}
```

And the _describe_floating_point_error function:

```
inline const char* _describe_floating_point_error(DWORD code)
{
    if (code && _EM_ZERODIVIDE)
        return FP_ZERODIVIDE_DESCRIPTION;
    ...
    return "Unknown floating point error";
}
```

In the case of a divide-by-zero, this works fine - GetExceptionCode returns a DWORD which includes _EM_ZERODIVIDE (0x00000008).

However, this __except clause is fired off when there is a worse error as well - such as a seqmentation fault, and in my latest case a missing function that was meant to be in a dll.  In this last case, GetExceptionCode returns:

```
11000000011011010000000001111110
```

I have yet to identify what error or errors this represents, but it *does* include _EM_ZERODIVIDE (i.e. 00000000000000000000000000001000), so _describe_floating_point_error incorrectly identifies it as a divide-by-zero.

My problem now is to identify why GetExceptionCode is returning a code which includes the divide-by-zero flag when the immediate problem does not relate (directly) to a divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this myself just to take it of the "stack":

It seems that the two protections do in some way interact, but the upshot is that the SIGSEGV protection (the most important one) *does* get triggered.  Although the additional warnings of a floating point error are unhelpful and misleading, they are not a deal-breaker.